# Zero supported device when publishing to Google Play

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, google-play

I am running into the zero supported device issue when publishing an Android application. I upload an APK, and Google Play tells me there is zero supported device.

My manifest is pretty simple, the only thing apart from the `<application>` section is this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I have no file in `app/libs`. I am using Android Studio.

The build.gradle file looks like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.the.application"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 902
        versionName "0.9.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        production {
            packageName "com.the.application"
        }

        test {
            packageName "com.the.application.test"
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:android-integration:3.1.0'
}
```

Any clue what could cause that?

Comment: possibly the use of API 20 as the targeted version? only a guess since API 20 is only found on wear devices

Comment: like @tyczj said I would look at that as the culprit. You can chance it by going into your properties and setting your compile version to something like 19.

Comment: `targetApiVersion` is not used in Google Play device filtering (only for runtime compatibility functionality). Can you post your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: I tried changing to `targetSdkVersion 19`, this doesn't make any difference. The `AndroidManifest.xml` is just the line I have above  plus the application section, do you want to see it?

Comment: I dont really see anything that would cause no supported devices if the targetedSdk didnt work