# No supported device when upload to Google play

Tags: android, google-play, device

I see many questions in this topic, but I could not find the solution here: [Zero supported device when publishing to Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26262303/zero-supported-device-when-publishing-to-google-play) or here: [No supported device for my Android app in Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33262399/no-supported-device-for-my-android-app-in-google-play).

My app uses permissions and there is no uses-feature in my code so the required:false parameter could not help. I insert the support screens lines too, but nothing changes.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.borbas.rawedding"
android:versionCode="3"
android:versionName="1.2" >

<supports-screens
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />



<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!--
 The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps.gps" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyAPKFe0-mXI4rHR6iU8u9INT7inyp8E7Y0" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.borbas.rawedding.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.borbas.rawedding.SaveTheDate"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/title_section1" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.borbas.rawedding.Screenplay"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/title_section4" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.borbas.rawedding.SaveTheDate_old"
        android:label="@string/title_section1" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.borbas.rawedding.MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_section1" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.borbas.rawedding.WhereIsTheLove"
        android:label="@string/title_section2" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.borbas.rawedding.WhereIsTheLove_old"
        android:label="@string/title_section2" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.borbas.rawedding.Countdown"
        android:label="@string/title_section3" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.borbas.rawedding.Playlist"
        android:label="@string/title_section5" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

I use one library: org.apache.http.legacy.jar

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.borbas.rawedding"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
}
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("keystore.jks")
        storePassword "xxxxxxx"
        keyAlias "keystore"
        keyPassword "xxxxxxx"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    //compile 'cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.4.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
}
```

I tried to delete all permissions, but the result was the same. I tried to add compatible-screens, but the result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem.
The solution was that I had changed the manifest file. Under the application tag I have got 2 uses-library tag. In the end of the line I have added

```
android:reqiured="false"
```

And I have added a third uses-library tag with the used org.apache.http.legacy.jar:

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy.jar" android:required="false" />
```

And now I have got 8872 supported device.